# Handle .NET DataGridViewCheckBox Changed Event

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

How can I handle a`CheckedChanged` event for a cell in a `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`?

**Note:** If applicable, I prefer VB.NET answers over C#, but I'll accept either.

Comment: Both answers essentially the same, I picked the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try attaching a handler to the DataGridView.CellValueChanged event; it's fired when any cell in the GridView changes, and will provide your handler information about the particular cell that changed. If the cell is a DataGridViewCheckBoxCell, the only data change that could happen would be that the checkbox was set or cleared. You can delegate that information to a more specific handler method, either through direct invocation or by raising your own event that other handlers listen for.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to handle the `CellValueChanged` event.

This code could be of help to you.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValueChanged
    Dim checkColumnIndex = 1 'replace this with the appropriate method to get the checkbox column's index'
    If e.ColumnIndex = checkColumnIndex Then
        'do something
        Debug.Print("Cell " & Chr(e.ColumnIndex + 65) & e.RowIndex & " has changed.")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Just for your information, the `Debug.Print` statement I added outputs to the debug console which cell has changed in the format `Cell L## has changed`. It's pretty rudimentary anyway.